# VBoxGuestAdditions Error 112

Tags: linux, oracle

[image]

How to fix this error that occurs while trying to install VBoxGuestAdditions?

Answer (score 0):

you should install the devel package of your kernel, and update your system, after this try to install VBoxGuestAdditions :

version of kernel : `uname -r`

search the devloppement package of your kernel : `yum search kernel-devel-...` some thing like that.

install it and update your system : `yum install kernel-devel-...`

```
                                `yum update`
```

and install your VBoxGuestAdditions